# Swagger Editor : ERROR Server not found or an error occurred

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am newer in Swagger tool. I try to test my **Restfull** application with **swagger editor**. I used basic authentication to access the web service.

In the **Swagger-UI**, the preview looks correct, i.e. Content-Type: `application/json` and the json is in the body.But When I send GET request from the Swagger editor to server, I got an error.

```
ERROR Server not found or an error occurred
```

**My Swagger**

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "Swagger Petstore (Simple)",
        "description": "A sample API that uses a petstore as an example to demonstrate features in the swagger-2.0 specification",
        "termsOfService": "http://helloreverb.com/terms/",
        "contact": {
            "name": "Swagger API team",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "url": "http://avfg.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "MIT",
            "url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
        }
    },
    "host": "127.0.0.1:8xxx",
    "basePath": "/v1",
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/facedetect/{username}/{albumname}/{imagename}": {
            "get": {
                "description": "Returns all pets from the system that the user has access to",
                "operationId": "findPets",
                "produces": [
                    "application/json",
                    "application/xml"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "username",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "tags to filter by",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "albumname",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "maximum number of results to return",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "imagename",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "maximum number of results to return",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "pet response",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/pet"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "default": {
                        "description": "unexpected error",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/errorModel"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "pet": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tag": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "errorModel": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "code",
                "message"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "code": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "message": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming your server responds to what you have configured: http://127.0.0.1:8610/api/v1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

Its CORS issue. My browser was blocking cors requests. I have installed a **Chrome extension** that adds **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to outgoing requests.

Comment: I downloaded and still not able to allow the request.. Is there anything else I need to do after that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have your server running.

If you have swagger installed, you can do

```
swagger project start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar problem

this is CORS, but :

in nodeJS i have set:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE, OPTIONS')
  res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  next();
});
```

but it helps only when request was without authorization (api-key). To make it works I have to change and use:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

hope it is helpfull